# Loading in Listview. Loads data from last entry into all rows

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a list of songs. Each list item should contain title, artist, time the song starts and some album art.
I can't seem to get it to work properly, each time I try it only loads the data from the last entry into all the rows.
I've read about ViewHolders and image loading libraries and tried implementing what I found with no luck.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
List data;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    String imgURL = SongListFragment.imgURL;

    if(convertView == null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listitem, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        TextView timeInfo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.timeInfo);

        title.setText(SongListFragment.title);
        artist.setText(SongListFragment.artist);
        timeInfo.setText(SongListFragment.starttime);

        Picasso.with(vi.getContext()).load(imgURL).into((ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.img));
        Log.d("Image", imgURL);

    }       

    return vi;

}

}
```

---

```
public class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

interface OnHttpGetListener{

    public void httpGetCompleted(String response);
    public void httpGetFailed(String error);

}

private OnHttpGetListener mListener;
private boolean mGetFailed;
private AndroidHttpClient client;

public HttpGetTask(OnHttpGetListener listener) {

    mListener = listener;
    client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {

        HttpGet uri = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(uri);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        resp.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        resp.getEntity().consumeContent();
        out.close();
        client.close();
        return out.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        mGetFailed = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();

    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

    if(mGetFailed) {

            mListener.httpGetFailed(response);

    } else {

            mListener.httpGetCompleted(response);

    }

   }

}
```

---

```
public class SongListFragment extends Fragment implements OnHttpGetListener {

ListView listview;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
static String imgURL = null;
static String title = null;
static String artist = null;
static String starttime = null;
static String endtime = null;

public SongListFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_fragment, container, false); 
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songlist);
    getJSON();

    return rootView;

}

private void getJSON(){

    HttpGetTask jsonGetter = new HttpGetTask(this); //registers to listen callbacks
    final String jsonUrl = "http://stark-castle-5854.herokuapp.com/songlist"; //url to json
    jsonGetter.execute(jsonUrl); //starts the async task

}

public void httpGetCompleted(String response) {

    // this gets called when the background task
    // to get json is completed without errors            
    try {

        JSONArray newJArray = new JSONArray(response);

        for(int i = 0; i < newJArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject json = newJArray.getJSONObject(i);
            title = json.getString("title");
            artist = json.getString("artist");
            starttime = json.getString("starttimeutc");
            endtime = json.getString("stoptimeutc");

            //all entries do not have an img resource
            if(json.has("img")){
                imgURL = json.getString("img");
            }else{                  
                imgURL = null;
            }

            long sTime = Long.parseLong(starttime);
            Date date = new Date(sTime);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd, HH:mm:ss");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
            String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

            Log.d("test", "Time: " + date);

            //hashmap to store values for the listview in
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Title", title);
            map.put("Artist", artist);
            map.put("Start", "Starts: " + formattedDate);
            map.put("End", endtime);
            map.put("ImgURL", imgURL);

            //add hashmap values to arraylist
            listEntries.add(map);           

            Log.d("test", "Success! Artist: " + artist +
                    " Title: " + title +
                    " Start: " + starttime +
                    " End: " + endtime +
                    " ImgURL: " + imgURL);          
        }

        //add arraylist to listview
        ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), listEntries,
                R.layout.custom_listitem,
                new String[] { "Title", "Artist", "Start"}, new int[] {
                    R.id.title, R.id.artist, R.id.timeInfo});

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").into((ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.img));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

public void httpGetFailed(String error) {
    // this gets called when the background task fails to get json
    Log.e("GetFail", error); // printing to error            
}

 }
```

Please help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Remove the *if(convertView == null)* condition. Otherwise use a holder and set your TextViews out of the **IF** bloc.

Comment: Ok, I tried removing the if statement but the results are the same. I've been trying to understand how using a holder would work but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it. Any tips on that? @Rami

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment, you are saving data in static variables. In this case after executing the for loop, the last entries will be saved in all those static variables. So there is only one entry which is last, stored. And in getview view you are accessing those variables every time, which means you are accessing same values for all rows.

To solve this, you need to access the data which you are passing as List(Maps). Do a get call on this and store it as object. Then get the properties of those objects.

Something like this in your adapters `getview()`

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    String imgURL = SongListFragment.imgURL;

    if(convertView == null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listitem, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        TextView timeInfo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.timeInfo);

    // NOTE THAT THIS PSEUDO CODE YOU NEED TO GET THE LIST POSITION AND MAP POSITION HERE TO ACCESS TITLE<ARTIST AND STARTTIME.
        title.setText(data.get(position).title);
        artist.setText(data.get(position).artist);
        timeInfo.setText(data.get(position).starttime);

       Picasso.with(vi.getContext()).load(imgURL).into((ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.img));
        Log.d("Image", imgURL);
    }       
    return vi;
}
```

Also I would suggest you to use ViewHolder pattern in `getView()` which is a standard way of inflating data inside Listview.

UPDATE:

```
title.setText(data.get(position).get("Title"));
artist.setText(data.get(position).get("Artist"));
timeInfo.setText(data.get(position).get("Start"));
```

Something like above should help you to get the data from list of hashmaps.

Hope you understood and hope this helps.

Comment: is correct, why your using the static references and the variables, possible leaks and incorrect way of coding. Use data model classes, use adapter add or addAll methods and checkout the tutorials for the adapters.

Comment: @EagleEye , I don't really understand tbh, I'm sure your answer would've helped a lot if I did. Should I remove all the static variables in my fragment? How do I get the list position and map position and how do I use that information? I've read about ViewHolder patterns but I don't really understand how to use them either.

Comment: @jitainsharma Why? Because I don't know better. I'm still learning and I'm trying my best to make sense of these problems I'm facing with my code.

Comment: @androidSw , we're all here to resolve the problems and along with this for letting know about the mistakes. Please don't take it personally and just grabs the points, if you found any thing wrong or the better way to implement, always feel free to do so.

Comment: Here is beutifull article about implementing ViewHolder pattern https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html